# Getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, during making http4 call in Apache camel route

Tags: http, apache-camel

I Am getting below exception from target server. I am migrating camel http component to http4 component.

```
2018-11-27 01:17:34,156 | ERROR | ernal.req.queue] | DefaultErrorHandler              | 81 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.3 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:ip-172-16-11-197-60068-1543219848548-41:1:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ip-172-16-11-197-36927-1543219848013-31-14). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

**HTTP4 Request headers(not working flow)** -

```
POST /GenieWebService/documentgenerator.asmx HTTP/1.1  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Length: 28955  
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8  
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate  
Authorization: Basic ZXNidXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==  
Host: xmz.ab.a.aaa(This is not actual ip)  
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)   
breadcrumbId: ID-ip-abc-ad-ac-abc-36927-15432193242455-7-90    
EXTR_SERVICE_URL: http://abs.ab.a.abc/GenieWebService/documentgenerator.xmzx  
X-Forwarded-For: 111.93.62.106, 165.225.106.106  
X-Forwarded-Port: 80  
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

**HTTP request headers (Working flow)**

```
POST /GenieWebService/documentgenerator.asmx HTTP/1.1  
Content-Length: 66831  
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8  
Authorization: Basic ZXNidXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==  
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=lairgud4nkaledjpuzarfqj0  
Host: abc.ab.a.abc
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1    
breadcrumbId: ID-ip-abc-ab-a-abc-34162-1542796372800-25-80  
EXTR_SERVICE_URL: http://abs.ab.a.abc/GenieWebService/documentgenerator.asmx   
X-Forwarded-For: 112.196.86.34, 165.225.106.89  
X-Forwarded-Port: 80  
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
```

*As per my understanding issue seems with cookies headers. In http4 request headers i am not able to see cookies header while it is in http headers.
Can someone plz help here what is the issue and if it is with cookies headers then how I can add cookies. I am using spring dsl and apache-camel 2.16.3 version.*

Answer (score 0):

You can set a 100ms timeout on the client by specifying http4://foo?httpClient.soTimeout=100. When a timeout occurs it will probably throw an exception that you can handle like so:

```
onException(IOException.class).to("direct:timeouts");

from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,simple("format=json&count=${in.headers.count}"))
.to("http4://www.host.com/someapi?httpClient.soTimeout=100")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.JACKSON,MyResponseType.class)
.to("bean:SomeBean?method=echo");

from("direct:timeouts").to("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used httpClient.socketTimeout=180000 and not using bridgeEndpoint option so camel will use http url that i am setting in headers. Below are the my route.

```
<route> 
    <from uri="{{document-service.esb.new.document.internal.req.queue.name}}"/>     
    <convertBodyTo type="javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource" charset="utf-8"/>    
    <process ref="document-serviceHttpUrlResolver"/>      
    <removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*"/>    
    <removeHeaders pattern="JMS*"/>    
    <setHeader headerName="SOAPAction">    
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">function:properties('document-service.esb.new_genie.document.service.soap.action')</xpath>  
    </setHeader>                
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpUri">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">in:header('EXTR_SERVICE_URL')</xpath>
    </setHeader>
    <!--CamelHttpUri value will be - http://xyz.xy.x.bcd/WebGenie/DocumentGenerator.svc-->              
    <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">function:properties('http.content.type.value')</xpath>
    </setHeader>                                                            
    <process ref="document-serviceSoapWrapper"/>
    <log message="*** A request message sent to New Genie service: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="document-service"/>                
    <to uri="http4://abc.ab.a.abc/GenieWebService/documentgenerator.asmx?httpClient.socketTimeout=180000"/>         
    <convertBodyTo type="javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource" charset="utf-8"/>               
    <to uri="{{document-service.esb.new.document.internal.resp.queue.name}}{{document-service.esb.internal.queue.parameters}}" pattern="InOnly"/>
</route>
```